# Visual Studio Local DB, Created new table still throws table not found. ASP.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, localdb

I have created a new table in local db in visual studio. My project is a basic project in asp.net mvc. Even though the table is in database still the program throws object name dbo.table_name not found. Can someone please help me to fix this?
I have attached all the screenshots.

[all screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6zkOD.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/RRrTy.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di9Ue.png)

Answer (score 0):

can I get your Solution explorer screenshot,
If there is any edmx file then you can update or create your table in edmx diagram

Comment: Hi, I could not find any emdx file in my solution explorer

Comment: did you gave name of table in model.cs using [Table("Table_Name")]